# UICollectionView animation doesn't show data

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

i want to add animation to collection view that the list very slowly moves up and down, after collection view reload data i'm start timer and add method for repeatedly animation, there is my code, The animation behavior is very unusual And during the animation I lose list data. 
there is my code how can solve this? 
thanks for reply.

```
 fileprivate func startTimer() {

    if timer == nil {

      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(addAnimationToCollection)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

  }
  func scrollToIndexPath(path: NSIndexPath) {
    let atts = self.collectionView!.layoutAttributesForItem(at: path as IndexPath)
    self.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: atts!.frame.origin.y - self.collectionView.contentInset.top)
    self.scrollPoint = self.collectionView!.contentOffset
    self.scrollingUp = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y > self.endPoint!.y

    self.scrollTimer?.invalidate()
    self.scrollTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:0.01, target: self, selector: (#selector(scrollTimerTriggered(timer:))), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

  func scrollTimerTriggered(timer: Timer) {

    let dif = fabs(self.scrollPoint!.y - self.endPoint!.y) / 10000.0
    let modifier: CGFloat = self.scrollingUp ? -2 : 2

    self.scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: self.scrollPoint!.x, y: self.scrollPoint!.y + (modifier * dif))
    self.collectionView?.contentOffset = self.scrollPoint!
    let maximumOffset = self.collectionView.contentSize.height - self.collectionView.frame.size.height
    if self.scrollingUp && self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y < maximumOffset {
      self.collectionView!.contentOffset = self.endPoint!
      timer.invalidate()
    } else if !self.scrollingUp && self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y >= self.endPoint!.y {
      self.collectionView!.contentOffset = self.endPoint!
      timer.invalidate()
    }

  }
  fileprivate func invelidTimer() {

    if timer != nil {
      timer?.invalidate()
      timer = nil
    }
    if scrollTimer != nil {
      scrollTimer?.invalidate()
      scrollTimer = nil
    }
  }
  @objc func  addAnimationToCollection() {

        let currentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset.y
        let maximumOffset = self.collectionView.contentSize.height - self.collectionView.frame.size.height
        if maximumOffset - currentOffset < 0 {
             let first : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
          self.scrollToIndexPath(path: first)
        }
        else {
            let last : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.collectionList.count - 1, section: 0)
          self.scrollToIndexPath(path: last)

        }

  }
```

Comment: Better do animation in willDisplayCell without timers.

Comment: In my opinion, you might probably not need  `UIView.animate` because ` .scrollToItem` already does animation part. moreover you might be trying to scroll to an item which has not been populated yet

Comment: @GaneshSomani i want to animate very slow but .scrollToItem animation is very fast.

Comment: @SharadChauhan i try your suggestion but  that's not what I want.

Comment: @GaneshSomani i'm edit my question and improve my code. Now collection view scroll slowly to down of list, but still i have a problem with scroll to top slowly.

Comment: `but still i have a problem with scroll to top slowly.` - Do you mean it scrolls to top at a faster speed. this should be due to the animation duration. Lets say you scroll down each cell of height (distance) 100 px in 1 sec and then you got to top of all these cells in 1 sec (if 10 cells then 1000 px)... naturally the speed would be different